# How to design Classifier interface, different classifiers and data storage?

Tags: c++, design-patterns

I have a class:

```
class TextClassifier {
public:
  void init(const std::string& file);

  TextType classify(const std::string& text) const;

private:
  HashMap<...> data_;
}
```

Function init loads some statistics from file into HashMap and function classify makes Naive Bayes classification.

I think it is a good idea to make a refactoring, so that user of this class can provide different classifiers and different types of DataStorage.

But I am a little stuck because I am not good at design. Could you please suggest be some good designs here? Could you also suggest some literature on this topic? Thanks!

Comment: are you trying to use factory pattern?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should have a look at the strategy pattern: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern